# Define body for an interface method

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface and I implement this interface in a class like this:

```
    interface ITest
    {
        bool Method();
    }

    class MyClass:ITest
    {
        bool ITest.Method()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool Method()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What does the method ITest.Method() in class do?

Comment: `ITest.Method()` is an explicit implementation of the `ITest` interface's `Method` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, if you have the following code:

```
ITest first= new MyClass();
```

`first.Method()` will call `bool ITest.Method();`

or if you have :

```
MyClass second= new MyClass();
```

`second.Method()` will call `bool Method()`